# If statement in Django template always runs the code no matter the condition is True or False

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm using a Key-Value model to make static template's data dynamic. This is my model's code:

```py
    class SiteDataKeyValue(models.Model):
        key = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Text title")
        value = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")

        def __str__(self):
            return self.key
```

For each static page, e.g. About us or Contact us, first I've created the texts in the admin panel. Then, I've written the views below:

```
    class ContactUsPageView(ListView):

        """In this view we are fetching site data from database, in a function named get_context_data.
        In this function, we filter the model for objects that contains the word 'contact', therefore
        fetching data referring to the about page only. After that the context list is sent to the
        template, and there with a for loop and an if statement, each key, value set is chosen for the proper place.
        """

        model = SiteDataKeyValue
        template_name: str = "core/contact-us.html"

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ContactUsPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context["contact_page_data"] = self.model.objects.filter(key__contains="contact")
            return context
```

Finally, in the template, I'm trying to use these data with a `for loop` and an `if statement` as shown below:

```
    {% for text in contact_page_data  %}
        {% if text.key == "contact us factory address" %}
            <p class="card-text"><i class="bi bi-geo-alt me-2">
                {{ text.value }}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

I have just one object with this exact key "contact us factory address" in my database. But when the template is rendered, the icon `<i class="bi bi-geo-alt me-2">` which is INSIDE of the `if statement`, gets printed 11 times (NOTE: Just the icon gets printed 11 times, and the value actually gets printed just once)! (11, is the total number of objects the `ContactUsPageView` view has sent to this template containing the word "contact".) Why is this happening? Why my icon that is INSIDE the if statemnet is shown 11 times instead of just once?

UPDATE: This problem was solved by adding `</i>` closing tag and there was no errors in other codes.

Comment: The code seems fine. The only thing I noticed is that it doesn't have a closing tag for the icon i.e `</i>`.
If the issue still persists, try to print the `text.key` inside for-loop  to debug that.

Comment: That was it! The closing </i> tag solved the issue. Thank you very much.